# How can I put my skype notification settings in a public git repo

Tags: linux, git, skype, dotfiles

I maintain key configuration files in a public git repo - I'd like to put my skype configuration in it too, because I find the default configuration way too noisy.
The newer version has started pausing videos being played in VLC.

Besides notifications, there's a bunch of stuff I change to make it less intrusive - it's getting annoying configuring these settings on each client and keeping them in sync.

The ~/.Skype/config.xml seems to contain a lot of data that is private and can't be hosted in a public space.

What are my options

Comment: Use a private git repo

Comment: @Wutnaut I find needing to clone it on machines I don't trust quite often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd probably do:

1. Write a script (using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2) or a similar tool) to extract the private parts to a different XML file.
2. Write a script to merge the extracted parts back.
3. Publish the pruned XML and both the scripts.

Comment: THanks, I ended up writing a ruby script that add the bits I need.